# How do you track all tables and views created by dbt?

Tags: dbt

We are using `dbt` in our project, and we found it's not easy to track "orphan" tables. These are tables or views created by `dbt` for which there is no `matching` current model.

These came about when a `.sql` file got renamed, or a view got converted to a table, etc...

Is there a way to find all of these orphan tables and views? Or at least a way to clear them out.

Ideas:

- Use pre or post hooks to maintain a table in the database with all views/tables created by `dbt`
- Schemas?

Note:

- We are using MSSQL if it matters

Answer (score 1):

Our team also used SQL Server and we have a macro we run as part of our CI for this. Here is the [Pull Request](https://github.com/dbt-msft/tsql-utils/pull/58/), but we have yet to merge it, so you'll have to copy the macro yourself. The readme also has informatino on how to use it.

I'll update this answer once tsql-utils v0.8.0 is officially released!

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. What is the difference between dbt-sqlserver and tsql-utils? I see you are a developer in both projects.

Comment: dbt-sqlserver is the main adapter for using SQL Server. tsql_utils is a package of helpful macros. The pacakge let's you use other popular dbt packages (e.g. dbt-utils and dbt-date) as well as some TSQL specific macros. dbt-sqlserver and tsql_utils are separated because you don't necessarily need tsql_utils to get started. better to start with simple and add complexity later on